# Monitor AKS container/pod status from pod running in different cluster/context

Tags: azure, kubernetes, monitoring

I have applications running in different cluster, like below (say as example)

```
 cluster1 - for scratch work
 cluster2 - as staging env (pods running application )
 cluster3 - as testing env (pods running application )
 cluster4 - monitor app
```

All the AKS cluster are connected in the network, a monitoring app is running on `cluster4`, which has custom monitoring dashboard. I am trying to add the container/pod status of app running on `cluster2` and `cluster3` to that dashboard.

Is there a way to fetch the container/pod status from the app running in `cluster4` either using java/REST API/shell.

I came across Kubernetes java client [InclusterClientExample](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/examples-release-12/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/InClusterClientExample.java).

Is there any better approach for this situation to fetch the container/pod status of the application running on different cluster.

Comment: are you using AKS?

Comment: yes AKS (azure kubernetes service)

Comment: why cant you use the azure monitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/

Comment: let me check the documentation, possibly this might be one approach.

Comment: What monitoring app is running on cluster4? As you are using cloud env is always best to use integrated monitoring, however you could also use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) like in [this guide](https://medium.com/thg-tech-blog/monitoring-multiple-kubernetes-clusters-88cf34442fa3). You just want to monitor all resources from all your clusters?

Comment: cluster4, runs custom spring boot java application which has a dashboard, with different data metrics. i could use monitoring tools, just looking to see if there is a simple java client which gets the pod status within this application.

Comment: @Tim did you try to use Azure monitor or you prefer to stay with your option with spring boot java app with dashboard?

Comment: @PjoterS - I will be using Azure REST API to fetch the logs from Log Analytics workspace. I was able to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With many other options, tried out `camel-kubernetes` component. This uses kubernetes-client managed by fabric8.

- If using minikube, set and start the application.
- use `minikube dashboard` or  `kubectl proxy --port=8080` so the cluster can be accessed from host machine.
- add the camel-core and camel-kubernetes dependencies to the project

```java
package com.learning.camel.examples.prog3;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class ListPodsInK8s {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
        context.addRoutes(new RouterToAccessK8s());
        context.start();
        
        ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
        template.start();
        template.sendBody("direct:input1","example");
        Thread.sleep(3000); // sleep 3 seconds
        }finally {
            context.stop();
        }       
    }
}
```

- code that will route to fetch the data

```java
package com.learning.camel.examples.prog3;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.Pod;

public class RouterToAccessK8s  extends RouteBuilder{

    public String host = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"; // use az command to get server url
    public String authToken = "";  // fetch the token using az command in case AKS
    public String certPath = "C:\\Users\\tim\\.minikube\\profiles\\minikube\\client.crt"; //minikube 
    public String certKey = "C:\\Users\\tim\\.minikube\\profiles\\minikube\\client.key"; // minikube
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        from("direct:input1")
        .toF("kubernetes-pods://%s?clientCertFile=%s&clientKeyFile=%s&namespace=default&operation=listPods", host,certPath,certKey)
        .log("pod size: ${body.size()}")
        .process(exchange -> {
            List<Pod> pods = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
            System.out.println("NameSpace | PodName | Status");
            pods.stream()
            .forEach(pod -> {System.out.println(pod.getMetadata().getNamespace()+ " |  "+ pod.getMetadata().getName()+" | "+pod.getStatus().getPhase());});
        })
        .end();
    }
}
```

output:

```
NameSpace | PodName | Status
default |  ngnix | Succeeded
kube-system |  coredns-74ff55c5b-26drq | Running
kube-system |  etcd-minikube | Running
kube-system |  kube-apiserver-minikube | Running
kube-system |  kube-controller-manager-minikube | Running
kube-system |  kube-proxy-b97ss | Running
kube-system |  kube-scheduler-minikube | Running
kube-system |  storage-provisioner | Running
kubernetes-dashboard |  dashboard-metrics-scraper-c95fcf479-x4bgq | Running
```

For Azure, `az aks get-crediential --file -` can be used to fetch the master server url (host) and access token info.

Answer (score 1):

Another options was to enable Log Analytics API.

- create a workspace and use REST API to fire query. below is at a high level of how to do it.

  - If AAD is setup, get the TENENT ID info.
  - Register App, create a Service principal.  (provides application (client) id)

    - Within the SP, add a secret key. (note this down, since it won't be viewable later)
    - Add API Permission, select Log Analytics

      - Grant Delegate permission (Data.Read) and Application Permissiong (Data.Read) which was in my case.
  - In Log Analytics workspace, Access Control (IAM), add the Service principal and provide Reader access. ( workspace-name, resourceGroup-name, workspace-id, subscription-id to be noted)

Per the [link](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/1-Tutorials/ARM-API).
First we need to fetch the access_token using the SP and Tenet id. Few of the screenshot in this link is old.

Using curl command:

1. Fetch token

```
curl -vX POST -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[SP application(client) id]&client_secret=[Client secret created in SP]&resource=https://management.azure.com/' https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENENT_ID]/oauth2/token
```

2. Fetch log info

```
curl -vX post -H "Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN-FROM-ABOVE]" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Prefer: response-v1=true"-d @samplequery.json https://api/loganalytics.io/v1/subscriptions/[subscription-id-of-workspace]/resourceGroups/[Resource-group-name-of-workspace]/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/<workspace-name>/api/query?api-version=2020-08-01
```

Sample query file

```json
{ 
 "query": "Perf | where CounterName == 'Available MBytes' | summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)",
  "timespan": "PT12H"
}
}
```

output would be the result of the query.